# css height percentage issue

Tags: css

I have a block level element containing 25 floated blocks,
I set the `width:20%` and `height: 20%`

depending on the height there is sometimes a gap, but width is always correct.

```
#grid{
  width: 880px;
  height: 333px; 
  background: blue;
}
#grid a{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background: red
}
```

please see http://jsfiddle.net/wVC5j/

how can i I ensure the gap at the bottom doesn't exist?

Comment: works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/wVC5j/1/

Comment: There is a gap because when you apply 20% to the parent height, you get a floating point number which is then rounded for the height. That means that you can get 1-2px gaps. Try setting the parent height to `330px` http://jsfiddle.net/wVC5j/2/

Comment: any way around this, or will i need to make sure the height is divisible by 5?

Comment: its odd behaviour that the width is not rounded, but height is

Comment: Its a wide-known problem and John Resig has written an article about it. You may want to check it out. http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved the problem using `20.15%` height instead of just 20.

This does cause a bit of overflow at times, but from my tests, no blue appeared when the height was changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/wVC5j/3/

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it was for a grid that covers an image, so has to add upto 100%

Comment: Perhaps then contain this grid inside a container of fixed height and width and set `overflow: hidden` such that the width does not go over 100%?